# What is the correct pronunciation of the word “ma’am”?

Tags: pronunciation, pronunciation-vs-spelling, ae-raising

Back in the day, the word *ma’am* (when addressing the Queen) was always pronounced “marm”. British TV shows from before the 80s confirm this.

In the movie *The Queen*, we are told that the correct pronunciation for *ma’am* is “ma’am” as in “*ham*”, and not “ma’am” as in “*farm*”. Some people seem to think this has always been the case. But it has not.

Is this pronunciation a modern development?
Is it a preference of the current sovereign?

Or have we been pronouncing *ma’am* wrongly throughout the centuries?

Comment: Here you can listen to the Brittish pronunciation as "maa-single-quote-eem" :) http://www.thefreedictionary.com/ma%27am

Comment: Do you know for a fact that the correct pronunciation was the one rhyming with *farm*, "throughout the centuries" until the 80s? How? (Obviously TV shows don't go back more than a century…)

Comment: *The King's Speech* also has a bit where future-Queen-Mum says it's pronounced "ma'am as in ham".

Comment: @Guffa, thanks but that's not quite what I'm driving at. I know how ma'am is pronounced in vernacular speech. I'm interested in the specific pronunciation of the word "ma'am" with respect to addressing a monarch. It was "marm" before the 80s, and then these days we are told it is "mam".

Comment: Oh, and an unrelated video just to add to the confusion: [Bensonmum](http://www.dailymotion.com/video/x4xr8v_jamesir-bensonmum-shows-dick-and-do_fun) (about 1:35 to 2:00).

Comment: @ShreevatsaR, you're quite right, though I suppose no one really knows how anything was pronounced before TV and radio. However, in period dramas depicting characters from before the 20th century, the pronunciation is always "marm". I assume it had been a tradition that has been carried on from way back. Because it deviates from vernacular pronunciation of ma'am, I'm assuming there's a reason for the older actors to do it that way.

Comment: @Martha, that's precisely why I'm trying to figure out when this shift happened. The King's Speech (excellent movie, by the way) is a post-"The Queen" movie. If you watch older period dramas, you'll rarely hear the "ma'am as in ham" pronunciation. Perhaps it has always been "ma'am" as in ham and the BBC got it all wrong when they started making those dramas? I don't know.

Comment: I think (but cannot prove) that the ma'am-as-in-farm pronunciation was always incorrect - it's how people in Hollywood (or lower-middle-class people in England) *imagined* the upper crust pronounced the word, because ma'am-as-in-ham was how *they* pronounced it, so that obviously couldn't be good enough for the Queen, could it?

Comment: I would love to see some actual data on this question, however.

Comment: @Martha, it's possible -- it's also possible that it's a northern pronunciation. Also, this comment here is an interesting data point: http://forum.wordreference.com/showpost.php?s=3fc39778950abf7921ff276ab4c09094&p=2913043&postcount=5

Comment: @Martha: I’m not quite so sure that *ma’am-as-in-farm* has never been upper-class — at least, I can’t find any evidence one way or the other, and don’t have any relevant personal experience.  Searching google books for `"yes mam"`, `"yes marm"`, `"yes mem"` etc. gives many useful results to see which groups within the lower classes were perceived as using which pronunciations… but unfortunately, older authors didn’t represent upper-class accents phonetically nearly so often, so it’s harder to work out how the upper classes pronounced things by this method!

Comment: @Martha: incidentally, what leads you to think that *ma’am-as-in-farm* was never upper-class?  Even if it’s just personal experience, that’d still be the nearest thing to evidence that any of us have found so far…

Comment: @PLL, no experience, just the aforementioned logic of "If I pronounce it as in ham, then the Queen must pronounce it differently, because she's upper class and I'm not".

Comment: @Gilead: You are missing the point completely. If you listen to it you might get it... :)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This is an interesting question!  I can’t find any documentation specifically on the issue, so I don’t have a conclusive answer, but here anyway is a lot of relevant information, and a bit of further speculation.

The OED lists various pronunciations:

> Brit. /mam/, /mɑːm/, U.S. /mæm/, /mɑm/; (unstressed) Brit. /məm/, U.S. /əm/, /mˌ/.

It also sheds some light on the recent historical usage:

> The γ, δ, and ε forms [respectively *mem*, *mim*; *mum*, *mom*; and *’m*] represent pronunciations formerly common in British regional usage and in the speech of domestic staff and others of similar status; such forms and pronunciations are also well attested in U.S. regional use, especially in *yes ma’am* (see *yessum* adv.) and *no ma’am*, and as the second element in *school-marm* n. Compare *marm* n.
>
> Buckingham Palace protocol (c1990) directed that ‘the Queen should be addressed as “Ma’am” (to rhyme with jam).’

It also includes, later:

> In 1936, R. W. Chapman ( S.P.E. Tract ii. 241) observed that ‘Except to royal persons, the contraction (whether mahm or măm) seems to be going out.’

This is all informative, but also a bit confusing.  The main thing that’s clear is that the variety of pronunciations goes back quite a long way.

The second thing is that in modern BrE, the usage of *ma’am* is so restricted that it’s very hard to disentangle “what people now use” and “what Buckingham Palace asks for”.  It’s a prescriptivist’s dream!

The third is that the OED itself seems a bit confused: the very pronunciation that the Palace asks for, /mæm/, is one which the OED lists only as U.S. usage.

The big question this leaves unresolved is: is it only recently that the Palace has asked for “jam”, or was this already officially preferred in the past?

Another factor which might be involved is how in many words, the vowel /a/ (of *farm*) is partly shifting to /æ/ (of *ham*) in prestige BrE accents, and the vowel of *jam*/*ham* in these accents has changed.  In eg the early 20th century, in upper-class British accents, the vowel in *ham*, *jam* etc. was more raised and fronted than today, somewhat closer to *hem*.  Conversely, words like *glass*, *class* were uniformly pronounced with the long *ah* vowel, /a/.  In many lower-class accents, *ham* was much like today, with /æ/, and *grass*, etc. were also pronounced with this vowel.

Since then, the stigma of perceived lower-class and regional accents has decreased, whereas a stigma of being ‘too posh’ has become more widespread; so the raising/fronting of *ham* is now very rare, and the pronunciation of *grass* with the *ham* vowel /æ/ is somewhat more common among RP speakers.

Given that this shift involves many class issues, and the alternation of /a/ and /æ/, I suspect it may have influenced the pronunciation of *ma’am* somewhat.  I’m pretty sure that the shift in the vowel of *ham* is relevant, given the older spellings of *ma’am* as *mem*, *mim* listed in the OED.  The relevance of the change in *grass* is much more speculative.

Comment: While we're speculating, it's also possible that the original TV/radio pronunciation of *ma'am* as /mɑːm/ ("mahm") was itself a hypercorrection, based on the class issues you mentioned — because in many words using /ɑː/ instead of /æ/ signified upper classes, people may have imagined that in talking to the queen, their familiar /mæm/ or /mam/ or whatever must be "corrected" to /mɑːm/. Just a wild thought. :-)

Comment: The OED doesn't use /æ/ at all in transcribing British pronunciations because it uses [Clive Upton's transcription system](http://www.phon.ucl.ac.uk/home/wells/ipa-english.htm). The symbol /a/ can be taken as equivalent to /æ/ (it transcribes "ham" with /a/).

Answer (score 4):

Just from personal experience, it has *always* been "ma'am as in ham" for female royals after first using "Your Majesty" or "Your Royal Highness".

*Always* in the sense that this was what my parents used when they needed to, and taught me to use with [Princess Alice of Athlone](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Princess_Alice,_Countess_of_Athlone); my father helped organise the Coronation in 1953, so it certainly covered the second half of the twentieth century, and probably earlier.

"Ma'am as in hem" was a traditional Indian Empire pronunciation for European women.

Comment: I, too, have good reason to know. It's definitely /mæm/ and not /mɑːm/.

Comment: I appreciate the personal insight. However, IMHO "always" goes back significantly further than 70 years or so.

Answer (score 3):

Interestingly in spite the proletarian implications, it's always 'ma'am as in harm' to a lady judge (who doesn't happen to be your worship, your honour, or my lady...so usually a District Judge)!

Comment: I can't see any reason to downvote this: it's a relevant fact, and the 'proletarian implications' are part of the question.

Answer (score 3):

From my experiences of military personnel and police officers in the UK, both of whom use the word ma'am to address female, superior officers; I can tell you that it is commonly pronounced as "marm" (with the letter r, being a non-rhotic one). This has been the case for several decades, at least.

Answer (score 2):

A current example may be found in the latest James Bond movie, 'Skyfall'. Bond addresses M as 'marm'. So does his co-agent, Eve. This is consistent with the military pronunciation reported by Tristan, above. Despite MI6 being civilian, Bond and Eve have military backgrounds.

Comment: This does not answer the question.

Answer (score 1):

Inspector Lewis (Kevin Whately), in *Lewis*, addresses his chief as “Ma’am”, and uses the long *a* that rhymes with the one a Londoner uses in both *father* and *farther*, rather than the *a* that rhymes with *ham*.

Answer (score 1):

The spelling *"schoolma'am"* seems to have been replaced by the spelling *"schoolmarm"* between 1870 and 1920, while *"schoolmam"* seems to be mainly American English (and quite rare even in the U.S.).

[Google Ngram](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=school+ma+%27+am%2Cschoolmarm%2Cschoolmam%2Cschoolma%27am&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=6&smoothing=7) for British English:

[image]

This would imply that *"ma'am"* was pronounced *"marm"* in RP.

Answer (score 1):

Here's some interesting info.

**ma'am**

Walker's PD (1828): no data

The Phonetic Dictionary of the English Language (1913): /mæm/

EPD-11 (1956): /mæm/

EPD-17 (2006) and EPD-18 (2011): /mɑːm/ or alternatively /mæm/

LPD-3 (2008): mæm (main variant), mɑːm

Fowler's 2004: /mæm/

Room 1986, The Dictionary of Britain: /mæm/

Answer (score 0):

In my personal experience, the Queen and other female royalty are the only people who would be called ma'am (to rhyme with jam) in this day and age.  We were taught that this pronunciation is restricted to the royal family.  Female judges and senior officers in the forces would be ma'am (pronounced as mahm). In the days of domestic service, ma'am had many variations from mahm to 'um (e.g. 'yes 'um'), but not the 'royal' pronunciation.

Comment: I should think that referring to a Mother Superior as “mom” would come off as a bit too informal.

Comment: Isn't the correct address "Reverend Mother" in that particular instance?

Answer (score -2):

M-W also has it as "mam like ham".   If you look at the origin of the contraction:  "madam" --> "ma'am", it would seem a little unusual to throw an "r" sound in the mix.

Comment: Well, the only accents that would pronounce it as "marm" are non-rhotic. In these accents, "r" at the end of a syllable only affects the pronunciation by modifying the preceding vowel, it doesn't correspond to any consonantal sound. "Father" and "farther" are synonyms. Merriam-Webster's pronunciation is undoubtedly true for current American English, but it doesn't give any information about if the historical pronunciation was different.

Comment: Homophones, not...

Comment: +1 I think this is a sensible etymological approach to take for guessing the original pronunciation.

Answer (score -3):

This is called "intrusive r," and is tied up with what is called rhoticity (basically variants of the pronunciation of the "r"). It is part of regional dialects and is encountered in certain areas of the US (such as Baltimore and parts of Pennsylvania "wash"pronounced "warsh"), and I know it also exists in the UK (obviously).

Comment: Not quite. I wrote "marm" as an approximation of the pronunciation, but it's actually pronounced "mAHm" (non-rhotic). UK residents know what I mean.

Comment: I’m pretty sure this isn’t what’s going on — I think when the OP says “pronounced like *marm* ”, they mean the non-rhotic pronunciation of *marm*, i.e. what a rhotic speaker would write as *mahm*.  I don’t remember ever hearing *ma’am* pronounced with an intrusive *r* in BrE.  Similarly, the intrusive *r* that occurs in BrE is not words like *wash*, but words like *Kafkaesque* (-> *Kafkaresque*) or *withdrawal* (-> *withdrawral*); it’s essentially a linking *r*, between morphemes within the word.

Comment: I do know what you mean because I have heard it. I didn't say it was rhotic I said it was tied up with rhoticity (both rhotic and non-rhotic)

Comment: @ PLL: I have seen "kafkaresque"  described as "an internal intrusive r"

Comment: @horatio: The question here is not about "mahm" vs "marm", but about ma'am rhyming-with-ham vs rhyming-with-farm (whether rhotic nor non-rhotic… the OP means non-rhotic, rhyming-with-palm).

Comment: I accept that. My further comments were directed at the commenters

Comment: @horatio: I appreciate you didn’t say it was rhotic, but if *marm* isn’t read rhotically, then I don’t see in what sense intrusive *r* is involved.

Comment: @PLL: Fair enough.

Comment: @tchrist: That's an odd pronunciation I cannot find in a dictionary (every dictionary I've seen has the 'l' as silent), but in any case I meant the standard 'pahm' pronunciation. I think that is clear enough when I say that it's rhyming with a non-rhotic "farm". Actually you don't even have to read my comment; its content is clear from the original question and many other comments above.

Comment: @tchrist: Interesting. I have 'l' in wolf, golf, gulf and polka, but not calm and palm. Anyway, point taken: what would be a good example to use in its place? (Rhyming with non-rhotic *farm* and with british *palm*)