# Native speakers never confuse sounds of 'ma'am' and 'man'?

Tags: pronunciation

1. ma'am /ˈmæm/ noun
2. man /ˈmæn/ interjection

When you said to a lady next to you, "Shall I bring your bag, ma'am?", a guy behind you said "Thanks, man!"

Have you ever had such a experience?

No confusion?

I know the last sound of each of them is different but I, a non-native speaker, don't think that I can definitely distinguish these two sounds in fast talking.

Can you, native speakers, distinguish them however fast they are spoken?

Comment: You might confuse them over the phone, but in person it's usually pretty clear who the person is talking to. In any case, there is more likely to be a diphthong in "ma'am" that would distinguish it from "man."

Comment: @Robusto Thank you. Diphthong. This is tough for me. There is no sound of diphthong in my first language. But I try harder. Thanks.

Comment: @Robusto: I have to say that for me, there is no diphthong in *"ma'am"*. For its pronunciation, [see this question](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/12113/what-is-the-correct-pronunciation-of-the-word-ma-am/76859#76859).

Comment: @PeterShor I've thought "schoolma'am" was written as "schoolmom"... How poor my English is... Thanks.

Comment: @PeterShor: I didn't say there *would* be a diphthong, only that it is more likely that there would be one. In other words, there *might* be one. I often hear people say "Mayum" there. I have never heard your pronunciation, of course.

Comment: They're probly both pronunced /mæ̃/ (i.e, with nasalized vowel but no final  nasal consonant) in rapid speech. Context will determine which is meant; if your addressee is feminine and you are acting politely, of if your addressee is male and you're acting informally.

Comment: @DeeM I don't know if you know this, but now you have more than 15 points, you can upvote questions. You can also decide to select a best answer for your post - if you think that one of the answers is good and answers your question properly :-)

Answer (score 5):

Calling someone "man" is extremely informal, while referring to a lady as "ma'am" is an overtly polite usage - so, one would take the clue from the proceeding word/words:

"*Hey*, Man" -
"*Good evening*, Ma'am"

"*S'up*, Man?" -
"*Can I help you*, Ma'am?"

"*Yo*, Man, *that what you pushin' these days*?" - "*Excuse me*, Ma'am, *is this your car*?"

Comment: +1 for pointing out the single most important factor: context. If you can find a context where either works, they'd probably be quite easily confused. Example: a phone conversation on a bad line. “I'm sorry, but… excuse me… [ma’am/man]… I'm sorry, but I can't hear you, could you speak more slowly please?” – Here, _ma’am_ would be an address, while _man_ would be an exclamation of annoyance at the bad line, injected in between the ‘actual’ sentences. Such examples are _very_ contrived, though.

Comment: @Oldbag Thank you. I did not know "man" is extremely informal. For example, calling your co-worker for more than a year with whom you've been to bar twice or three times "man" is extremely informal? Polite or impolite usage of words in English is very difficult for me. And, I don't know what is "Yo, Man, that what you pushin' these days?" meaning.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Thank you for new example. I understand what you said. BTW, to whom do you say "man" in real life? To friends for very long time? How about to female friends? Please tell me the atmosphere of "man".

Comment: _Man_ is informal, but not extremely informal. It is fine to call a (male) coworker that you're friendly with _man_. Greeting him with a “Hey man, how's it going?” is very unlikely to cause any offence. _Ma’am_, on the other hand is the female counterpart to _Sir_, and you'd never use it when greeting someone you were on friendly terms with. “Good morning, ma’am” would be how you'd address a (female) boss that you only know professionally and wish to be fairly formal with.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Thank you very much. The correct usage and meaning of "ma'am" is unexpected. I have to be careful when I call ladies. Thank you.

Comment: @DeeM - "Yo, Man, that what you pushin' these days?" means,  "Is that your car?"   It's kind of a joke, meaning:  it probably doesn't run very well, so you end up pushing  it from place to place.

Comment: @Oldbag Wow! wow... I can not say anything but "wow"... It is impossible for me to understand such a joke. but I am sure that there are as many jokes in English as in my first language, and they are out of grammar and rules. Anyway, cheers, man! :)

Comment: @Oldbag - "one would take the clue from the proceeding word/words" or sometimes from the succeeding words: "Ma'am, I'll have to ask you to step aside", "Man, that was harsh".

Answer (score 5):

The key word is **context**.

If you just say either of these two words, without context, *many* people may be confused as to which of the two you mean.

However, *in* context, this will rarely happen, because *man* is highly informal, both as a form of address, and certainly as an interjection, whereas *ma'am* quite formal.

For example, the interjection *man* would never be used together as *ma'am* like this:

> Man, it's hot! Can I offer you a cold drink, ma'am?

When you use *man* to address someone, it's also informal:

> You wanna cold beer, man?
>   * You wanna cold drink, ma'am?
>   Could I offer you a refreshment, ma'am?
>   * Could I offer you a refreshment, man?

The second and fourth variants are unlikely to be spoken by native speakers, because they mix different levels of formality. So in practice, the **context** will make the listener understand which of the two is meant.

---

As such, your confusion between the *m* and *n* sound is logical, the two *do* sound very similar, even to native speakers, which can sometimes lead to confusion, for instance when saying, or even spelling a name over the phone. *Em* and *en* are so close that it often gets clarified when spelling out a word or name (M as in Mary, N as in Never, or the NATO-alphabet, *Mike* versus *November*).

Whenever words are used *in context*, confusion doesn't happen that often, though. For instance, the *d* and the *b* can sound very similar, but nobody will think that

> The dog barked in the dark night.

actually is supposed to be

> The bog darked in the bark night.

Even though *bog* and *bark* are existing words!

Comment: Thank you for detailed explanation. It is very easy to understand. "Levels of formality" is good word for me. I misunderstood the situation where I use these two words, like "ma'am" for a lady I first met and "man" for a guy who is friendly to me and even I first met.

Answer (score 2):

I suspect that the reason that this is difficult for the Original Poster, is that as in many other languages, there is no syllable final contrast between /m/ and /n/ in Japanese. Notionally, the nasal consonant at the end of Japanese syllables in thought of as an 'N'. In fact in everyday speech the /n/ at the end of Japanesse syllables will merely be realised by a nasalised vowel.

This is also true, for example, of many Spanish speakers. There are no Spanish words that end with the letter 'M'. The only nasal consonant that we see in the orthography is 'N'. In spoken Spanish, therefore, many words will be pronounced with either an /n/, an /m/, or with /ŋ/ (the sound represented by 'NG') at the end of the syllable. This does not matter in Spanish, because there are no pairs of words that can be confused with each other because of a difference between /n, m,/ or /ŋ/.

Because of this, Spanish  speakers will often produce the wrong nasal at the end of an English word. So, we might hear /taɪn/ for the word *time*. They also sometimes find it difficult to distinguish /n, m, ŋ/ at the ends of words too. Japanese speakers often also mispronounce words ending in /n/ either by missing the actual /n/ out altogether and replacing it with a nasalised vowel, or by replacing it with /m/ or /ŋ/. They can also have problems hearing which nasal is being used at the end of a word, although it's easier if there's a following vowel.

For these reasons it is often difficult for speakers of other languages to distinguish the nasal consonants at the end of a spoken word, particularly if not followed by a vowel.

To make things even worse, it's also a fact that /n/ is very unstable in English - though /m/ and /ŋ/ aren't. What this means is that /n/ tends to undergo a process of assimilation when appearing before another consonant. So before bilabial consonants (those using the lips), it tends to become bilabial too, changing to /m/. In front of velar consonants (made at the back of the roof of the mouth) it becomes velar too, changing to /ŋ/. Before dental consonants (made with the tongue and the teeth) it also becomes dental, although in this case it is still recognised as an /n/.

What this means is that if the Original Poster heard the following:

- Shall I take your bags man, before they get wet?

This may well actually have been pronounced:

- Shall I take your bags ma**m**, **b**efore they get wet?

In oother words the /n/ in man will tend to change to /m/ before a following bilabial /b/.

Comment: Thank you. Your interpretation about our difficulties with pronunciation suppose to be correct. "Shall I take your bags man, before they get wet?" I definitely could not pronounce it correctly, especially "man, before". I feel that it is so busy to move my lips that I hardly make right lip-moves. I need much more practice. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure that many words that are not normally confused for each other could be confused if the speaker says the word quickly, if the surrounding environment is noisy, etc. So I wouldn't say that native English speakers NEVER confuse "ma'am" with "man", but it is certainly not a common problem.

Comment: I mean really I appreciate you.

Answer (score 1):

Native speakers of British English pronounce ma’am as /mʌm/ and use it only to address the Queen. So there is no danger of confusing it with man /mæn/ on this side of the Atlantic.

Comment: Native speakers of British English pronounce _ma’am_ in several different ways, depending on whom they are addressing (cf. the question that Peter linked to in his comment above). The word only ever rhymes with _man_ when addressing the Queen, though, that's true—and if you're wondering if someone just addressed QEII as _man_, then you're probably overthinking things. :-)

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet. ma'am does not ever rhyme with man. To begin with, the final consonant is different.

Comment: Well, yes. I meant ‘rhyme’ apart from the n/m distinction, which is what the question is all about, referring only to the quality of the vowel.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Thanks :) BTW, yesterday I watched UK TV show on YouTube. In that show, a girl was talking "Your singing was beautiful, man" to another woman. I am sure what she said because subtitles was provided by the show. Do girls often say "man" as well? The show was "VOICE UK" :)

Comment: That's using _man_ as an exclamation, not a form of address. It's more or less equivalent to “damn!” or “wow!”, depending on context: “Man, this food is good!” can be said with nobody else around just fine.

Comment: @fdb I usually pronounce *mum* as /mʌm/ . I've never heard another British English speaker use /mʌm/ for *ma'am*. I can't find that pronunciation in any dictionaries or pronouncing dictionaries either. Are you sure about that?